# Magento custom rest API works on localhost but throws internal server error on server

Tags: rest, api, magento, internal-server-error

We created a couple of custom API's that are working fine on localhost, but on the server one of them give's internal server error.

In the error log we got this:

```
[Fri Jul 14 16:06:46.397538 2017] [core:error] [pid 7894:tid 139744927274752] [client 5.2.174.151:40133] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: content-type
```

In the API we set the header content type to application/json

```
<?php header('content-type','application/json'); ?>
```

The php versions on localhost and server are the same 5.6.31

And this is the htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 768M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_value memory_limit 768M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset Off
AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html A0
ExpiresByType text/plain A0
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch 403 /\.git
<Files composer.json>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files composer.lock>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .gitignore>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess.sample>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .php_cs>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files .travis.yml>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files CHANGELOG.md>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files COPYING.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files Gruntfile.js>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files LICENSE.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files nginx.conf.sample>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files package.json>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files php.ini.sample>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files README.md>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files magento_umask>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
<FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# with AJAX withCredentials=false (cookies NOT sent)
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"  
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials  "true"              
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
RewriteEngine On                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you post what the actual header value comes out as? sometimes it gets UTF8 automatically added, and some (dumb) systems choke on that.

Comment: Hi, sorry for this late response, I get this info from header when I call the url of the API.     Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [1] => Date: Mon, 17 Jul 2017 08:05:51 GMT [2] => Server: Apache [3] => Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Jul 2017 07:56:23 GMT [4] => Accept-Ranges: bytes [5] => Content-Length: 3268 [6] => Connection: close [7] => Content-Type: text/html ) 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: Interesting... And you don't get that exception on localhost?

Comment: Nope, I don't get that exception on localhost, there everything seems to work fine. It's very strange...